# GitHub Repo Transfer

Tags: github

If I transfer my personal repo to an organization (created by me) will I be losing all the **insights** such as traffic history, pull requests, contributors, forks, etc from the original Repo?

Comment: What was the result of the transfer in the end? Did you lose all the insights?

Comment: I end-up not taking any risks and remained as it is

Answer (score 2):

Pull requests are preserved: see "[About repository transfers](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository#about-repository-transfers)"

> When you transfer a repository to a new owner, they can immediately administer the repository's contents, issues, pull requests, releases, project boards, and settings.
>
> Git information about commits, including contributions, is preserved

The traffic might not be preserved though: to be tested.